# Break or User input to separate copying of files?

Tags: python, loops, pause

I've looked around and haven't come across anything similar so..

I have several directories of files that need to be unzipped/moved to a specific folder(the same folder). The files that need to be unzipped are in this structure:

```
  -ZippedfolderA
    -unzipped filename: abc.txt
  -ZippedfolderB
    -unzipped filename: abc.txt
  -ZippedfolderC
    -unzipped filename: abc.txt
  etc..
```

So you see after they're unzipped they all have the same name, and thus overwrite one another.

Quick notes:

- No, I can't change the name after it's unzipped. These files get pulled into DB, and need to stay the name they're given.
- The difference between folders A,B,C is dates. Each folder has different dates. A=yesterday, B=daybeforeyesterday, C=3 days ago, etc.

So far my code unzips, compares dates, and moves the files to where they need to be. But I need to somehow pause the code after each dated folder so the DB can pull in the files in between unzipping. Otherwise the last to get unzipped overwrites the other two. I'm trying to figure out how/where I can use something like *Input* or *Break* to wait until the first set is pulled in, then continue to unzip the second folder, wait, then pull in the other folders and so on down the line. Here's my code up to this point...

```
def files_to_folders(filename):
    if f.endswith(".TXT"):
        ff = f[1:7]
        if ff == yesterday.strftime("%y%m%d"):
           print(ff, f)
           fnew = f[12:] # Change back to [13:]
           os.rename(os.path.join(root,f), os.path.join(root, fnew))
           shutil.copy(os.path.join(root,fnew), wescorpex)
           shutil.copy(os.path.join(root, "DLY"), wescorpex)
        elif ff == daybefore1.strftime("%y%m%d"):
            print(ff, f)
            fnew = f[12:] # Change back to [13:]
            os.rename(os.path.join(root,f), os.path.join(root, fnew))
            shutil.copy(os.path.join(root,fnew), wescorpex)
            shutil.copy(os.path.join(root, "DLY"), wescorpex)
        elif ff == daybefore2.strftime("%y%m%d"):
            print(ff, f)
            fnew = f[11:]# Change back to [13:]
            os.rename(os.path.join(root,f), os.path.join(root, fnew))
            shutil.copy(os.path.join(root,fnew), wescorpex)
            shutil.copy(os.path.join(root, "DLY"), wescorpex)
        elif ff == daybefore3.strftime("%y%m%d"):
            print(ff, f)
            fnew = f[10:]# Change back to [13:]
            os.rename(os.path.join(root,f), os.path.join(root, fnew))
            shutil.copy(os.path.join(root,fnew), wescorpex)
            shutil.copy(os.path.join(root, "DLY"), wescorpex)
    return filename

targets = [(folder, create(folder, destpath)) for folder in destdir]
#Create directories based on ZIP folder
try:
    for dirname, full_path in targets:
        for filename in srcfiles:
            if dirname == filename[0:7]:
                shutil.copy(filename, full_path)

        # Extract all files within folders to new directory root
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(os.path.join(rootpath, full_path)):
            for files in fnmatch.filter(files,pattern):
                zipfile.ZipFile(os.path.join(root,files)).extractall(root)
                os.remove(os.path.join(root,files))
        #Rename extracted files in new direct root with end of filename
        walkpath = os.path.join(rootpath,full_path)
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(walkpath):
            for f in files:
                files_to_folders(f)

except(IOError):
    print("there was an error.")
    time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: inside `if f.endswith(".TXT"):`  you check again `if f.endswith(".TXT"):` - it is useless.

Comment: Is there some way you can tell if the files have been pulled into the DB? You could put a loop that repeatedly checks whether the files have been pulled. When it sees that all the files have been pulled, it can break out of this loop, and then the main loop that copies files can continue.

Comment: furas - This was old code that was needed before I added it to the now seen function. I have removed it so it no longer confuses you. However, you have not helped in regards to my original question. Barmar - The files get pulled manually into the DB. However, that's a good idea. Perhaps I can try some kind of prompt to pop up if it detects the files, and then ask the user to wait until the files have been moved before continuing the loop?